# Xcode not Recognising New Custom Classes

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I am creating new custom classes for my project, but they're not showing or being recognised by Xcode seemingly. I am simply unable to select the class from the drop-downs.

I have had to resort to renaming a previous ViewController just so I can get it to recognise that one. However I know I will need new classes (VCs, table cells etc).

**More importantly though I'm getting an error message for my custom View Controller called 'MatchesVC' so atleast it is trying to load this Custom Class (which I had to rename from a previous VC):**

```
import UIKit

class MatchesVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self


}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return MatchDataCell()

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}}
```

**CAN ANYONE PLEASE PLEASE HELP THIS POOR NOOB NUMPTY?**
I'm following course material, but this problem is definitely isolated to me and my project unfortunately. I'm stumped.

For "tableView.delegate = self" it is returning the error "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0). Also stating FATAL ERROR: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb). I literally have no idea what this could be or could mean. Things seemed to be working great before and they do so, when I change the sub class from MatchesVC to UIViewController but I need that functionality.

---

I also have a table view cell (created via Cocoa Touch) below with the following code:

Any idea why on earth my TableViewCell would not recognise this or show up in the custom classes?

```
import UIKit

class MatchDataCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var profileImg: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        profileImg.layer.cornerRadius = profileImg.frame.size.width / 2
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

I have tried to clean the Derived Data folder twice and have restarted Xcode and the Mac I am working on.

I have ensured I am referring to the write type of class, but still no success. Would it be worth uninstalling and reinstalling Xcode for this?

---

Comment: Need some more information about your setup, what is the process you use to create a class?

Comment: 1) File > New > File.. 2) Select Cocoa Touch Class (for iOS) 3) Select Subclass of UITableViewCell and rename the Class appropriately to MatchDataCell. Language Swift. Select Target and "Create".

Comment: What do you mean by 'not recognizing'? What error do you get? Can you post a screenshot / error log?

Comment: No errors. Just I can't select the class for specific ViewControllers or Cells. I don't believe Xcode is recognising them because my table cell shows blank when I manually type this class 'MatchDataCell' into the custom class.

Comment: Tell a lie, I am now getting an error message. It doesn't seem to want to apply my custom ViewController but seeing no errors for the MatchDataCell so assume it's not just showing because Xcode is being lazy. If you can't tell, I am new to this coding malarky but I am learning fast'ish...